# changing the order of values in a variable in sas data (row-wise ordering )

Tags: sas

My sasdata output is like this.

[image]

Can we make the values in a particular order ?(change the order of rows)

ie In the order of "less than 10 lakh, between 10-20 lakh,between 21-30.... above 1 crore".

I want to change the row order. Right now rows are ordered in ascending order. Can we do that it in a manual order?

Comment: A better way would be to store the actual income, then create a format to display it in the required text.  You can then easily sort on the income column.

Comment: Storing ranges / measurement units as text is usually a really bad idea. You'll end up in a trouble when someone later wants to change the 31 - 50 lakh range to be 31 - 40 and 41 - 50, or change the spelling somehow or...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DATA Out.Temp_order;                                                                                                                    
  SET Out.HSI_income_range;                                                                                                             
if income_range="Above Rs. 1 Crore" then dummy_column= 6;                                                                               
if income_range="Between Rs. 10-20 lakh" then dummy_column= 2;                                                                          
if income_range="Between Rs. 21-30 lakh" then dummy_column= 3 ;                                                                         
if income_range="Between Rs. 31-50 Lakh" then dummy_column= 4  ;                                                                        
if income_range="Between Rs. 51 Lakh – Rs. 1 Crore" then dummy_column= 5;                                                               
if income_range="Less than Rs. 10 Lakh" then dummy_column= 1;                                                                           

RUN;                                                                                                                                    

PROC SORT DATA = Out.Temp_order;                                                                                                        
  BY dummy_column;                                                                                                                      
RUN;                                                                                                                                    

data Out.HSI_income_range (Drop=dummy_column);                                                                                          
  set out.Temp_order;                                                                                                                   
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

Build a format and order the data after the format value:

```
PROC FORMAT;
INVALUE I_range
'Above Rs. 1 Crore' = 6
'Between Rs. 10-20 lakh' = 2
'Between Rs. 21-30 lakh' = 3
'Between Rs. 31-50 Lakh' = 4
'Between Rs. 51 Lakh - Rs. 1 Crore' = 5
'Less than Rs. 10 Lakh' = 1
;
RUN;


DATA Temp_order;
  SET HSI_Income_Range;
  order_data = INPUT(IncomeRange,I_range.);
RUN;

PROC SORT DATA = Temp_order;
  BY order_data;
RUN;

data HSI_Income_Range (Drop= order_data);
  set Temp_order;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you . We are almost correct.. When I run your code, I got the order like "between 31-50 lakh, between 51 lakh- 1 crore, less than 10 lakh, between rs 10-20 lakh, above 1 crore".. from the third row , it is correct

Comment: Did you just do copy and paste or write the code by your column-values?. I saw there are some typos in my code depending your Columnvalues.

do a 
    proc print data = temp_order;
     run;
after the sort, if the order data column has a . instead of a number, then i spelled something wrong at the format statement.
The Format needs the exact same spelling as in the income_range column

Comment: I edited my code, sometimes you spell lakh with L and sometimes with l, i did not checked your example, can you test again?

Comment: I used if statement. Thank you very much for helping